Xray not working on Docker base image (FROM scratch)
When I upload my Docker base image to JFrog Artifactory and scan it using Xray it produces an empty SBOM and shows no violations or certificates.
I created a Docker image using the contents of a rootfs tarball (produced from a custom Buildroot OS) and was able to get it running within a Docker container as well. Used a Dockerfile to create the image and implemented the "FROM scratch" method to make it a base image.
Are there certain configurations that I need to add to my image for the JFrog Xray scan to work?

Trying to test somethings out and realize that JFrog Xray utilizes the package manager stored within the Docker image (apt,dpkg,etc). Whereas buildroot doesn't really contain a package manager as it is configured to be light and ready to go without the need of updates or extra installations. Is there any way that JFrog Xray could scan an image without a package manager? Or maybe even scan the build process?
